# Variation on Existing site

Tags: 2013, variations, multilingual

I am trying to understand how variations works with SharePoint 2013. I have already gone through the details, so understand the basics. I have read these:
http://blog.consejoinc.com/2011/01/creating-multilingual-sites-in.html
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/sharepoint_quick_reads/2013/08/11/sharepoint-2013-variations-initial-setup-and-configuration-for-variations-site/

All the content i found suggests that we create everything from scratch and and after setup, new content and objects would be synced by jobs.

**Now my scenario:** I have a site collection with no variations configured for it. There is already content, lists and some web parts on the site. Now the client wants to make it multilingual.

1. So is it possible to use the existing site as source site and create some target variant?
2. How to replicate existing content, Objects and web-parts to the target site?
3. Is there any other option than using variation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching i found that it is not possible.
[This](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c65dff53-81e8-4c0c-8bbd-28a09b991e2f/variation-with-existing-sharepoint-site?forum=sharepointdevelopment) URL supports my answer.